# JavaFX WebView Not Loading HTTPS Page

Tags: ssl, webview, javafx-2

I have written a browser using the JavaFX WebView control. Everything is fine until I try to load an encrypted page. I try https://www.gmail.com and I get an "Unknown Error" in the exception property of the load worker. This only happens when I package the application as a stand-alone; when I run the project in NetBeans everything is fine. I am guessing it has to do with SSL certificates, but I tried pretty much everything I could think of, including importing each certificate in the trust store with "keytool," but nothing works.

Any ideas? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you package as standalone?

Comment: @jewelsea In the build.xml file, I uncommented the <target name="-post-jfx-deploy"> element and I set the nativeBundles attribute's value to "all" in the <fx:deploy> element. What gets me is that everything works as intended with the exception of the https sites. And I only get an "Unknown Error."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your browser work with https sites when launching from an IDE (Eclipse, Netbean)?
If so, the difference might be the JRE.
You might need to copy the file sunjce_provider.jar to the bundled JRE.
I use a Mac and sunjce_provider.jar is located in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext.

Comment: Thanks sooooo much for your answer. U's a genious!!! That was the problem. For a while I thought I was stuck and almost gave up and started to think of alternatives. For those who run in the same problem, check out this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_cookbook_using_drop)