# Native Bundle throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: javafx-2

I'm trying to build a native bundle, specially for mac os x, but also in windows. And in both environments the .app, .dmg, .exe get generated correctly, but when I run them, I get many java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException exceptions. For example:
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available

Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available

My program uses TLS, to establish xmpp connections. And also I have a webview with HTTPS which is not loading eighter.

Does anybody have any idea why this could be happening?
I should note that if I run the generated jar alone, it works fine, it only happens with the .exe and .app.
This is my build.xml fx:deploy code:

```
<fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" 
          nativeBundles="all"
          outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
  <fx:application name="${application.title}" 
                  mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
  <fx:resources>
      <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}"
                  includes="*.jar"/>
      <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
  </fx:resources>
  <fx:info title="${application.title}" 
           vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
</fx:deploy>
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't seen this post before: [JavaFX WebView Not Loading HTTPS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356633/javafx-webview-not-loading-https-page/13599131#13599131)

What's happening is that the jre's bundle doesn't include the /ext folder, so you have to copy it with a script when you build the bundle.